# react-boostrap Dropdown.Item custom jsx on clicking the item the dropdown does not close

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

i am trying to create a drop-down component where the user on clicking on a custom item, some code will be executed and then the dropdown will close.

Here is an example of what i am trying to achieve.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrapp-checkbox-dropdown-entcq

I am using react-bootstrap and react-bootstrap dropdown (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/).

---

i have tried to implement this using forwardRefs but i am still stuck

```
const AnalysisMenu = () => {
  const CustomToggle = React.forwardRef(({ onClick }, ref) => (
    <MenuIcon
      onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        onClick(e);
      }}
      ref={ref}
      className="analysisMenu__toggle-icon"
    />
  ));

  const CustomItem = React.forwardRef(({ data }, ref) => {
    if (data.url) {
      return (
        <li className="dropdown-item" ref={ref}>
          <a title={data.label} target="_blank" href={data.url}>
            {data.label}
          </a>
        </li>
      );
    }
    if (!data.url && data.action && data.actionLink) {
      return (
        <li
          title={data.label}
          ref={ref}
          className="dropdown-item"
          onClick={() => {
            switch (data.action) {
              case "1":
                somefunction1();
                break;
              case "2":
                somefunction2();
                break;
              case "3":
                somefunction3();
                break;
              case "4":
                somefunction4();
                break;
              case "5":
                somefunction5();
                break;
              case "6":
                somefunction6();
                break;
              default:
                break;
            }
          }}
        >
          {data.label}
        </li>
      );
    }

    return null;
  });

  const CustomMenu = React.forwardRef(
    ({ children, style, className, "aria-labelledby": labeledBy}, ref) => {
      return (
        <div ref={ref} style={style} className={`${className}`} aria-labelledby={labeledBy}>
          <ul className="list-unstyled flex-shrink mb-0" style={{ overflow: "auto" }}>
            {children}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  );

  return (
    <Dropdown className="analysisMenu" >
      <Dropdown.Toggle as={CustomToggle} id="dropdown-custom-components" />

      <Dropdown.Menu as={CustomMenu}>
        {menuItems.map((item) => (
          <Dropdown.Item key={item.id} as={CustomItem} data={item} />
        ))}
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};

export default AnalysisMenu;
```

So in this case i should say in the switch function

```
CustomToggle.click();
```

but i get an error that CustomToggle doesn't have a click function

Thank you in advance,
Andreas

Comment: on every checkmark you want your dropdown to get closed?

Answer (score 1):

you can use ref and set it to `Dropdown.Toggle` in order to close it after any action.

```
export const CheckboxDropdown = observer(({ items }) => {
  const togglerRef = React.useRef(null);
  const handleChecked = async (key, event) => {
    items.find((i) => i.id === key).checked = event.target.checked;
    // key is id and you can use the key or event.target.checked.
    console.log("Id: ", key, event.target.checked);
    togglerRef.current.click();
  };

  const handleSelectAll = () => {
    items.forEach((i) => (i.checked = true));
  };

  const handleSelectNone = () => {
    items.forEach((i) => (i.checked = false));
  };

  return (
    <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Toggle variant="primary" id="dropdown-basic" ref={togglerRef}>
        Properties
      </Dropdown.Toggle>

      <Dropdown.Menu
        as={CheckboxMenu}
        onSelectAll={handleSelectAll}
        onSelectNone={handleSelectNone}
      >
        {items.map((i) => (
          <Dropdown.Item
            key={i.id}
            as={CheckDropdownItem}
            id={i.id}
            checked={i.checked}
            onChange={handleChecked}
          >
            {i.label}
          </Dropdown.Item>
        ))}
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
});
```

Here is a example working.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrapp-checkbox-dropdown-forked-6d01t9?file=/src/CheckboxDropdown.js:1607-2758